# Date picker with spinner design in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Can someone tell me how i can implement this design of date picker in flutter?

[image: Dob Design]

Comment: Looks like a Picker to me: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoPicker-class.html. And for date specifically use this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoDatePicker-class.html

Comment: this looks like cupertino, is there any way so that i can stick cupertino date picker widget onto center of the screen,

Comment: Also if you are not looking for the Cupertino the,Ed Widgets you probably want https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView-class.html

Comment: for the same design, by any chance time picker is available?

Comment: @shanmkha by default, It is not available, You'll have to either create your own or you can use the suggested in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_holo_date_picker 
code snippet

```
DatePickerWidget(
      looping: false, // default is not looping
      firstDate: DateTime(1990, 01, 01),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030, 1, 1),
      initialDate: DateTime(1991, 10, 12),
      dateFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy",
      locale: DatePicker.localeFromString('en'),
      onChange: (DateTime newDate, _) => _selectedDate = newDate,
      pickerTheme: DateTimePickerTheme(
        itemTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19),
        dividerColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
    )
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_holo_date_picker/flutter_holo_date_picker.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'example',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: WidgetPage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class WidgetPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WidgetPageState createState() => _WidgetPageState();
}

class _WidgetPageState extends State<WidgetPage> {
  DateTime _selectedDate;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
            child: DatePickerWidget(
              looping: false, // default is not looping
              firstDate: DateTime(1990, 01, 01),
              lastDate: DateTime(2030, 1, 1),
              initialDate: DateTime(1991, 10, 12),
              dateFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy",
              locale: DatePicker.localeFromString('en'),
              onChange: (DateTime newDate, _) => _selectedDate = newDate,
              pickerTheme: DateTimePickerTheme(
                itemTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 19),
                dividerColor: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: zh locale is not applying on this picker. can you suggest me how to pick locale too

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 `Cupertino Picker` to create a `Custom Date Picker` connected with each other. Change the `magnification` value to get it center of the screen.

```
     CupertinoPicker(
      magnification: 1.5,
      itemExtent: 50,
      looping: true,
      }
```